# How to get access to specific dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating dynamically multiple elements and i want to get access to specific ones. I write this code to give a view of my problem as simple as i can.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  $('#generate').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<button id="addedButton' + (a) + '"type="button">button' + (a) + '</button>')
    $('#valuesArea').append('<div id="addedDiv' + (a) + '">button ' + (a) + ' clicked </div>')
    $('#addedDiv' + (a) + '').fadeToggle("slow");
    a++;
  })
  //this way i can get acces to only first element
  $(document).on('click', '#addedButton' + (b) + '', function() {
    $('#addedDiv' + (b) + '').fadeToggle("fast");
    b++;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divArea">
</div>

<button id="generate">
    Generate
</button>
<div id="valuesArea">
</div>
```

If i create multiple buttons of id `addedButton1,2,3 etc.` and click specific one i want to `.show()` suitable `<div>` with text. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Just a note, the `id` attribute must always be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data-target` attribute in `<button>` which contains target content `id`. So, you can easily toggle data by targeting particular content with unique `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  $('#generate').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<button id="addedButton' + (a) + '"type="button" data-target="addedDiv'+(a)+'">button' + (a) + '</button>')
    $('#valuesArea').append('<div id="addedDiv' + (a) + '">button ' + (a) + ' clicked </div>')
    $('#addedDiv' + (a) + '').fadeToggle("slow");
    a++;
  })
  //this way i can get acces to only first element
  $(document).on('click', "button[data-target]", function() {
    var targetData = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('#'+targetData).fadeToggle("fast");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divArea">
</div>

<button id="generate">
    Generate
</button>
<div id="valuesArea">
</div>
```

Comment: @Asfan_Shaikh can i add multiple elements to `data-target` and toggle more than 1?

Comment: You can add multiple elements in `data-target` but you have to change `data-target="addedDiv'+(a)+'"` with `data-target="#addedDiv'+(a)+'"` ('#' added). Change `$('#'+targetData)` with `$(targetData)` ('#' removed).  Now you can add multiple targets by separating them using `,`(comma)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the id of the button, you can add it to a data attribute, and grab that value in the .addedButton click function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  $('#generate').click(function(){
    $('#divArea').append('<button class="generatedButton" id="addedButton'+(a)+'" data-button-id="'+(a)+'"type="button">button'+(a)+'</button>')
    $('#valuesArea').append('<div id="addedDiv'+(a)+'">button '+(a)+' clicked </div>' )
    $('#addedDiv'+(a)+'').fadeToggle("slow");
    a++;
  });
  //this way i can get acces to only first element
  $(document).on('click','.generatedButton',function(){
    b = $(this).data('button-id');
    $('#addedDiv'+(b)+'').fadeToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div id="divArea">
</div>

<button id="generate">
    Generate
</button>
<div id="valuesArea">
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that you bind the click event only once to `#addedButton0`.

See the refactored code. I append a `data` attribute to the buttons which is used in the click event `$('#addedDiv' + $(this).data('a')).fadeToggle("fast");`. With this the variable `b` is no longer needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  $('#generate').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<button id="addedButton' + a + '" data-a="' + a + '" type="button">button' + a + '</button>')
    $('#valuesArea').append('<div id="addedDiv' + a + '">button ' + a + ' clicked </div>')
    $('#addedDiv' + a).fadeToggle("slow");
    a++;
  })
  //this way i can get acces to only first element
  $('#divArea').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('#addedDiv' + $(this).data('a')).fadeToggle("fast");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divArea">
</div>

<button id="generate">
    Generate
</button>
<div id="valuesArea">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to th element then use $(this) to get the particular id and access it as you want to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  $('#generate').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<button class="btn_class" id="addedButton' + (a) + '"type="button">button' + (a) + '</button>')
    $('#valuesArea').append('<div class="div_class" id="addedDiv' + (a) + '">button ' + (a) + ' clicked </div>')
    $('#addedDiv' + (a) + '').fadeToggle("slow");
    a++;
  })
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_class', function() {
  id = $(this).attr('id'); // To get the ID of the element
  $('this').fadeToggle("fast");
});
```

And since this is a $(document) query, you dont need to put this under ready function.
And I dont think you need to give id to the element if you only want to toggle it.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var a = 0;
      var b = 0;
      $('#generate').click(function() {
        $('#divArea').append('<button onclick="check('+(a)+')" id="addedButton' + (a) + '"type="button">button' + (a) + '</button>')
        $('#valuesArea').append('<div id="addedDiv' + (a) + '">button ' + (a) + ' clicked </div>')
        $('#addedDiv' + (a) + '').fadeToggle("slow");
        a++;
      })
      //this way i can get acces to only first element
      //$(document).on('click', '#addedButton' + (b) + '', //function() {
        //$('#addedDiv' + (b) + '').fadeToggle("fast");
        
        //b++;
      //})
        
    });
    function check(id){
          $('#addedDiv'+ (id)).show();
     }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divArea">
</div>

<button id="generate">
    Generate
</button>
<div id="valuesArea">
</div>
```